# How to transliterate Cyrillic to Latin using Python 2.7? - not correct translation output

Tags: python, python-2.7, translation

I am trying to transliterate Cyrillic to Latin from an excel file. I am working from the bottom up and can not figure out why this isn't working.
When I try to translate a simple text string, Python outputs "EEEEE EEE" instead of the correct translation.  How can I fix this to give me the right translation?? I have been trying to figure this out all day!

```
symbols = (u"абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхъыьэАБВГДЕЁЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЪЫЬЭ",
           u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'eABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'E")

tr = {ord(a):ord(b) for a, b in zip(*symbols)}

text = u'Добрый Ден'
print text.translate(tr)

>>EEEEEE EEE
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: This works fine for me. What happens when you run *just* `text.translate(tr)` (no `print`)? I get `u'Dobryj Den'`.

Comment: Please don't paste prompts and diareses in your code. It just makes it that much harder for others to test.

Comment: @Marc: Unfortunately that has become a far too common style here on SO...have a good text editor helps overcome it, though.

Comment: @martineau I'm not firing up emacs to test out someone else's code.

Comment: Seems to work for me, too, using Python 2.7.5 on Windows.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: If I run just  `text.translate(tr)` , I get `u'EEEEEE EEE'`. I am using Python 2.7.  I have tried closing and restarting Python and always the same answer- `EEEEE EEE`.  Is there a possibility that I have to uninstall and reinstall Python? I am very confused why this isn't working.

Comment: @Marcin: thanks for the tip- I will remember that next time!

Comment: @user2584342: What does `print symbols` show? What about `print tr`?

Comment: @Marcin: I find that when using proper Python interpreter output styling, communication about what is code and what is output is greatly improved. This post was oddly formatted, however.

Comment: @user2584342: Also, what does `print text` give, and what does `print text.translate(tr).encode('unicode_escape')` show?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps. But what is output can be signalled with comments just as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have tried what you have asked and here are my outputs:`print symbols` gives
`(u'????????????????????????????????????????????????????', u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'eABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'E")`
`print tr` gives
`{63: 69}`
`print text` gives
`?????? ???`
`print text.translate(tr).encode('unicode_escape')` gives
`EEEEEE EEE`

Comment: @user2584342: Then the way you entered your sourcecode is invalid. Is this directly in the terminal in a Python prompt or in source code?

Comment: @user2584342: the bottom line is that Python does not see unicode points, but only question marks in the first `symbols` value. That results in all question marks to be translated to `E`. `text` suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your *source* input is wrong. However you entered your `source` and `text` literals, Python did not read the right unicode codepoints.

Instead, I strongly suspect something like the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` variable](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) has been set with the error handler set to `replace`. This causes Python to replace all codepoints that it *does not* recognize with question marks. *All* cyrillic input is treated as not-recognized.

As a result, the only codepoint in your translation map is 63, the question mark, mapped to the last character in `symbols[1]` (which is expected behaviour for the dictionary comprehension with only one unique key):

```
>>> unichr(63)
u'?'
>>> unichr(69)
u'E'
```

The same problem applies to your `text` unicode string; it *too* consists of only question marks. The translation mapping replaces each with the letter `E`:

```
>>> u'?????? ???'.translate({63, 69})
u'EEEEEE EEE'
```

You need to either avoid entering Cyrillic literal characters or fix your input method.

In the terminal, this is a function of the codec your terminal (or windows console) supports. Configure the correct codepage (windows) or locale (POSIX systems) to input and output an encoding that supports Cyrillic (UTF-8 would be best).

In a Python source file, tell Python about the encoding used for string literals with a [codec comment at the top of the file](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Avoiding literals means using Unicode escape sequences:

```
symbols = (
    u'\u0430\u0431\u0432\u0433\u0434\u0435\u0451\u0437\u0438\u0439\u043a\u043b\u043c'
    u'\u043d\u043e\u043f\u0440\u0441\u0442\u0443\u0444\u0445\u044a\u044b\u044c\u044d'
    u'\u0410\u0411\u0412\u0413\u0414\u0415\u0401\u0417\u0418\u0419\u041a\u041b\u041c'
    u'\u041d\u041e\u041f\u0420\u0421\u0422\u0423\u0424\u0425\u042a\u042b\u042c\u042d',
    u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'eABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'E"
)
tr = {ord(a):ord(b) for a, b in zip(*symbols)}

text = u'\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0440\u044b\u0439 \u0414\u0435\u043d'

print text.translate(tr)
```